# Unable to see run service/ script in init.rc file in Andorid

Tags: android, shell, service, init

init.rc

```
service Test /system/bin/sh /vendor/bin/Test.sh
class main
oneshot
```

on late-init
   start Test

test.sh works well in terminal. It is intedned to create some directories e.g. mkdir in addition some print messages

But Service Test does not work at boot.

I am adb pushing init rc and rebooting

I want to know is it really needed to build complete SW for this init.rc change.

I do not see any error any log w.r.to my added part; however it is visible in rc file even after systen reboot.

Comment: I had got sucees over that; but do not why "ip" command in shell works.

Answer (score 0):

I did following:

1. Used cpp file and with Andorid.bp created a IP.bin file in /system/bin
2. In Vendor/etc/init/ created a separate Init_IP.rc, which would run service ( execute .bin) after boot complete.

This solved all of my problem.
"IP" commands not worked earlier since they are non-Toybox and part of /system/bin/, with .bin located in /system/bin/ have same SE state to make them work.